# Where does macOS store server details for @iCloud.com mail account?

Tags: icloud, mail.app, email, keychain

[image]My Mac has incorrect server settings for my iCloud.com email account.  For my primary user account on the Mac, Mail thinks that @iCloud.com is POP instead of IMAP, so I can't connect.  I don't know how this happened.  I can find no way to edit these settings. I can find the settings (server, port, SSL etc) for my other mail accounts in the PLIST files under Users//Library/Mail, but not for @iCloud.com.  Perhaps it is in a Keychain (Login?) but I do not know where.  It may be possible to fix if I can find it.  Running Mac mini M2, Sonoma.  FYI, I can connect to my @iCloud.com mail account normally from my iPad, or from a "test" new user account on the Mac.

Comment: What do you see in Mail > Settings > Accounts? Have you tried disabling and re-enabling Mail in System Settings > iCloud > Mail?

Comment: Yes, have disabled, re-enabled in iCloud settings.  Added what I see in Mail / Settings / Accounts for this account to the original question.

Comment: Given the steps you have already taken, a call to Apple may be the fastest way to resolve this issue.

Comment: Sadly I have already spent a few hours on chat and phone with Apple and managed to get it escalated one level, but it is clear the support team could not answer the actual question and were suggesting I try various standard help desk tactics, in the hope they might solve the problem.  I will keep trying to get them to escalate to Apple engineering.